# DSMR P1 - example frame CRC

Tags: c

I try to calc CRC for P1 message. CRC is calculate The CRC for P1 runs from the "\" to the "!" (inclusive). CRC16 uses no XOR in, no XOR out and is computed with least significant bit first.

P1 message:

```
/ISk5\2MT382-1000

1-3:0.2.8(50)
0-0:1.0.0(101209113020W)
0-0:96.1.1(4B384547303034303436333935353037)
1-0:1.8.1(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:1.8.2(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:2.8.1(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:2.8.2(123456.789*kWh)
0-0:96.14.0(0002)
1-0:1.7.0(01.193*kW)
1-0:2.7.0(00.000*kW)
0-0:96.7.21(00004)
0-0:96.7.9(00002)
1-0:99.97.0(2)(0-0:96.7.19)(101208152415W)(0000000240*s)(101208151004W)(0000000301*s)
1-0:32.32.0(00002)
1-0:52.32.0(00001)
1-0:72.32.0(00000)
1-0:32.36.0(00000)
1-0:52.36.0(00003)
1-0:72.36.0(00000)
0-0:96.13.0(303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F)
1-0:32.7.0(220.1*V)
1-0:52.7.0(220.2*V)
1-0:72.7.0(220.3*V)
1-0:31.7.0(001*A)
1-0:51.7.0(002*A)
1-0:71.7.0(003*A)
1-0:21.7.0(01.111*kW)
1-0:41.7.0(02.222*kW)
1-0:61.7.0(03.333*kW)
1-0:22.7.0(04.444*kW)
1-0:42.7.0(05.555*kW)
1-0:62.7.0(06.666*kW)
0-1:24.1.0(003)
0-1:96.1.0(3232323241424344313233343536373839)
0-1:24.2.1(101209112500W)(12785.123*m3)
!EF2F
```

For calc CRC I used this func;

```
uint16_t crc16 (const uint8_t *data, unsigned int length)
{
    uint8_t x;
    uint16_t crc = 0;

    while (length--) {

        int i;

        crc ^= *data++;
        for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i) {
            if (crc & 1)
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
            else
                crc = (crc >> 1);
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't get crc = 0xEF2F.

Can anyone help me where the problem may be ?

### UPDATE

I checked the crc from this example - https://www.netbeheernederland.nl/_upload/Files/Slimme_meter_15_32ffe3cc38.pdf and it also doesn't match. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Your program gives the same result as https://crccalc.com/ for CRC-16/ARC Maybe the data in the example from https://www.netbeheernederland.nl/_upload/Files/Slimme_meter_15_a727fce1f1.pdf has the wrong checksum?

Comment: I checked the crc from this example - https://www.netbeheernederland.nl/_upload/Files/Slimme_meter_15_32ffe3cc38.pdf and it also doesn't match. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: A friend promised to send me a true P1 telegram, so I can check. (my hypothesis is that the example in the PDF is wrong) And: yes: I coreected the CR/LF stuff.

Comment: ok then i am waiting for the information.

Comment: Hey, do you have true P1 telegram ?

Comment: My friend's smart meter appeared to just omit the CRC. The `!` is the last character in the telegram :[